# cy.spy on window.clearInterval function

Tags: javascript, cypress, sinon

In an application I'm developing I'm using setInterval along with clearInterval. I want to spy on the clearInterval in order to see that the method was called. Here is essentially what I'm doing

```
beforeEach(() => {
   cy.clock(new Date())
})

it('Test Scenario' => {
   const fn = cy.spy(document.defaultView, 'clearInterval')
   //also tried fn = cy.spy(window, 'clearInterval')
   ...
   ...
   ...
   //The clearInterval function is called upon entering the
   //`then` part but the stub is reporting it hasn't been called
   cy.tick(30000).then(() => {
    expect(fn).to.have.been.calledOnce
   })
})

afterEach(() => {
   cy.clock().invoke('restore')
})
```

The expect in the above snippet fails when I'm expecting it to to pass. Is the logic to initiate the spy valid|correct? Many thanks in advance as to any help regarding the above.

Answer (score 4):

Cypress uses a different `window` for the test and for the app. The `cy.spy(window...` is using the test window, but to spy on the app window you will need the `cy.window()` command.

```js
let spy;
cy.window().then(appWindow => {
  spy = cy.spy(appWindow, 'clearInterval')
})

... later

expect(spy).to.have.been.calledOnce
```

But there may be another complication, because `cy.clock()` puts `clearInterval()` in a proxy so it can control timing functions of the app, so you may not be able to spy on it.

If you find it's still not working, grab the return value of the `cy.clock()` and see if there's call information attached.

```js
let clock;
beforeEach(() => {
  clock = cy.clock(new Date())
})
```

or else specify that `clearInterval` should not be proxied

```js
beforeEach(() => {
  cy.clock(new Date(), ['Date', 'setInterval'])  // only proxy Date and setInterval
})
```

Comment: Hi @Ho'okano thanks for the response the first snippet doesn't work unfortunately...So if I don't proxy `clearInterval` in theory I could provide my own test implementation of that function which essentially verifies it gets called by the `APP`?

Comment: None-the-less, that's the correct way to do it. You most likely have some other bug not shown in the code. Can you improve the question to show how the interval is started?